# Get Column Range Based on Active Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to copy some data to the clipboard, from a Google Spreadsheet, by running a script - I want to minimize user error, this is the reason for the script. Depending on the active cell, I want the script to select 57 rows below the active cell and copy the values to the clipboard, in order to be pasted somewhere else. I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is the code that I have at the moment.

```
function copyDailySubsidy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rangeRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rangeCol = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var range = ss.getRange(rangeRow, rangeCol, 23).getValues();
  //var values = ss.getRange().getValues();

  Logger.log(rangeCol);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to copy the values of the range, or even select the appropriate range.  Any help that you can afford would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not achievable in Google Apps Script. Your script is running on a remote server, and has no access to a user's clipboard.